# I am trying to figure out if my model is linear or not linear

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I am doing a model for some mechanical engineering problem. I have 12 inputs/features and 19 outputs/responses. I have a dataset that contains a total of 100 datapoints ( I know it is not that much of a dataset). The thing is I know that the relationship between these inputs and outputs is NOT linear. However, when I fit a first degree linear regression to my data points, I get a very high R^2 (R^2=0.95). Also, my thinking is that as the polynomial degree increases, the model's R^2 should improve, but this ain't happening in my case.

My questions are: I) Is my model really a linear model or am I doing something wrong? Can a non-linear model fit perfectly into a linear model? Is there anyway I can be very confident that my model is really linear? II) Why the value of R^2 is not increasing as the polynomial degree increases?

```
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
names = X.columns
d = scaler.fit_transform(X)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=names)
X_normalized, y_for_normalized = scaled_df[[ "Part's Z-Height (mm)","Part's Weight (N)","Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)","Part's Surface Area (cm^2)","Material's Density (g/cm^3)","Layer Height (mm)","Infill Density (%)","Nozzle/Printing Temperature (C)","Platform Temperature (C)","Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)","Part's Orientation (Support's height) (mm)","Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)"]], data_set [["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)","Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)","Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)","Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)","Freshwater Consumption (m^3)","Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)","Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)","Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)","Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)","Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)","Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)","Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)","Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)"]]
Normalized_matrix = pd.concat([X_normalized,y_for_normalized],axis=1)
Normalized_matrix


Part's Z-Height (mm)    Part's Weight (N)   Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)  Part's Surface Area (cm^2)  Material's Density (g/cm^3) Layer Height (mm)   Infill Density (%)  Nozzle/Printing Temperature (C) Platform Temperature (C)    Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)  Part's Orientation (Support's height) (mm)  Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)    Climate change (kg CO2 eq.) Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)   Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)    Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)   Freshwater Consumption (m^3)    Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)    Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)    Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)   Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)    Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.) Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)   Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)    Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)   Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)  Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)

0   0.258287    0.022303    0.005030    0.000000    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.308259    0.040088    0.0778  0.0426  0.000039    0.0179  0.0933  0.000175    2.910000e-07    0.000892    0.001290    0.000541    0.034000    0.000101    2.750000e-06    0.000412    0.000152    0.000152    8.720000e-08    0.000118    0.00919
1   0.258287    0.022303    0.005030    0.000000    1.0 0.2 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.308259    0.036597    0.0620  0.0274  0.000036    0.0171  0.0464  0.000171    2.820000e-07    0.000443    0.001120    0.000520    0.033100    0.000098    2.670000e-06    0.000251    0.000144    0.000143    8.450000e-08    0.000111    0.00665
2   0.258287    0.027728    0.009557    0.000000    1.0 0.4 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.131007    0.031013    0.0573  0.0226  0.000035    0.0169  0.0311  0.000172    2.810000e-07    0.000297    0.001070    0.000518    0.033100    0.000098    2.670000e-06    0.000200    0.000142    0.000141    8.440000e-08    0.000109    0.00587
3   0.258287    0.027125    0.009054    0.000000    1.0 0.6 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.131007    0.031013    0.0550  0.0203  0.000035    0.0168  0.0239  0.000172    2.800000e-07    0.000228    0.001040    0.000517    0.033000    0.000098    2.670000e-06    0.000175    0.000141    0.000140    8.420000e-08    0.000108    0.00548
4   0.258287    0.028330    0.010060    0.000000    1.0 1.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.308259    0.031711    0.0530  0.0180  0.000035    0.0169  0.0165  0.000173    2.820000e-07    0.000157    0.001020    0.000519    0.033200    0.000098    2.680000e-06    0.000150    0.000141    0.000140    8.460000e-08    0.000108    0.00512
5   0.258287    0.022303    0.005030    0.000000    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.308259    0.040088    0.0803  0.0450  0.000039    0.0180  0.1010  0.000175    2.920000e-07    0.000965    0.001320    0.000542    0.034000    0.000102    2.750000e-06    0.000438    0.000154    0.000153    8.730000e-08    0.000119    0.00960
6   0.258287    0.062086    0.038226    0.000000    1.0 0.0 0.25    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.308259    0.040088    0.0935  0.0503  0.000047    0.0219  0.1080  0.000214    3.560000e-07    0.001040    0.001560    0.000662    0.041700    0.000124    3.370000e-06    0.000484    0.000186    0.000185    1.070000e-07    0.000144    0.01100
7   0.137212    0.021700    0.004527    0.000000    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.109655    0.030314    0.0713  0.0379  0.000036    0.0169  0.0806  0.000166    2.750000e-07    0.000770    0.001200    0.000511    0.032200    0.000096    2.600000e-06    0.000364    0.000144    0.000143    8.250000e-08    0.000111    0.00830
8   0.137212    0.021700    0.004527    0.000000    1.0 0.2 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.109655    0.029616    0.0584  0.0251  0.000034    0.0164  0.0407  0.000165    2.700000e-07    0.000389    0.001060    0.000499    0.031800    0.000094    2.570000e-06    0.000228    0.000138    0.000137    8.120000e-08    0.000106    0.00619
9   0.137212    0.028330    0.010060    0.000000    1.0 0.4 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.109655    0.028918    0.0564  0.0219  0.000035    0.0168  0.0291  0.000171    2.790000e-07    0.000278    0.001050    0.000514    0.032800    0.000097    2.650000e-06    0.000192    0.000141    0.000140    8.380000e-08    0.000108    0.00573
10  0.137212    0.028330    0.010060    0.000000    1.0 0.6 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.109655    0.028220    0.0540  0.0196  0.000034    0.0166  0.0221  0.000170    2.770000e-07    0.000211    0.001030    0.000511    0.032700    0.000097    2.640000e-06    0.000168    0.000140    0.000139    8.330000e-08    0.000107    0.00535
11  0.137212    0.027728    0.009557    0.000000    1.0 1.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.109655    0.027522    0.0514  0.0172  0.000034    0.0164  0.0150  0.000169    2.750000e-07    0.000143    0.000996    0.000506    0.032400    0.000096    2.610000e-06    0.000143    0.000138    0.000137    8.260000e-08    0.000106    0.00494
12  0.137212    0.021700    0.004527    0.000000    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.109655    0.030314    0.0739  0.0405  0.000036    0.0170  0.0887  0.000166    2.760000e-07    0.000848    0.001230    0.000513    0.032200    0.000096    2.610000e-06    0.000391    0.000145    0.000144    8.270000e-08    0.000112    0.00873
13  0.137212    0.061483    0.037723    0.000000    1.0 0.0 0.25    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.109655    0.030314    0.0868  0.0454  0.000045    0.0209  0.0949  0.000205    3.410000e-07    0.000907    0.001470    0.000632    0.039800    0.000119    3.220000e-06    0.000434    0.000177    0.000176    1.020000e-07    0.000137    0.01000
14  0.077118    0.021700    0.004527    0.039373    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.040474    0.054050    0.0837  0.0461  0.000041    0.0191  0.1020  0.000186    3.100000e-07    0.000972    0.001380    0.000576    0.036200    0.000108    2.930000e-06    0.000447    0.000163    0.000162    9.290000e-08    0.000126    0.00992
15  0.077118    0.021700    0.004527    0.039373    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.040474    0.054050    0.0864  0.0488  0.000041    0.0192  0.1100  0.000186    3.110000e-07    0.001050    0.001410    0.000579    0.036300    0.000108    2.930000e-06    0.000475    0.000164    0.000163    9.310000e-08    0.000127    0.01040
16  0.077118    0.021700    0.004527    0.039373    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.333333    0.040474    0.054050    0.0849  0.0473  0.000041    0.0192  0.1060  0.000186    3.110000e-07    0.001010    0.001400    0.000577    0.036300    0.000108    2.930000e-06    0.000459    0.000163    0.000162    9.300000e-08    0.000127    0.01010
17  0.077118    0.021700    0.004527    0.039373    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.866667    0.040474    0.054050    0.0831  0.0455  0.000041    0.0191  0.0999  0.000186    3.100000e-07    0.000955    0.001380    0.000576    0.036200    0.000108    2.930000e-06    0.000440    0.000163    0.000162    9.290000e-08    0.000126    0.00982
18  0.077118    0.021700    0.004527    0.039373    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 1.000000    0.040474    0.054050    0.0828  0.0453  0.000041    0.0191  0.0990  0.000186    3.100000e-07    0.000946    0.001380    0.000576    0.036200    0.000108    2.930000e-06    0.000437    0.000162    0.000161    9.280000e-08    0.000126    0.00977
19  0.077118    0.121157    0.087518    0.039373    1.0 0.0 1.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.040474    0.054050    0.1260  0.0682  0.000063    0.0292  0.1480  0.000285    4.750000e-07    0.001410    0.002090    0.000881    0.055500    0.000165    4.480000e-06    0.000658    0.000248    0.000247    1.420000e-07    0.000192    0.01480
20  0.474185    0.016275    0.000000    0.039373    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.636497    0.074296    0.0930  0.0530  0.000044    0.0205  0.1210  0.000198    3.310000e-07    0.001150    0.001520    0.000617    0.038700    0.000116    3.120000e-06    0.000517    0.000175    0.000174    9.920000e-08    0.000136    0.01120
21  0.474185    0.016275    0.000000    0.039373    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.636497    0.074296    0.0951  0.0552  0.000045    0.0206  0.1270  0.000198    3.320000e-07    0.001220    0.001540    0.000618    0.038700    0.000116    3.130000e-06    0.000540    0.000176    0.000175    9.940000e-08    0.000136    0.01160
22  0.474185    0.016275    0.000000    0.039373    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.333333    0.636497    0.074296    0.0939  0.0539  0.000044    0.0205  0.1230  0.000198    3.320000e-07    0.001180    0.001530    0.000617    0.038700    0.000116    3.130000e-06    0.000526    0.000175    0.000174    9.930000e-08    0.000136    0.01130
23  0.474185    0.016275    0.000000    0.039373    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.866667    0.636497    0.074296    0.0925  0.0526  0.000044    0.0205  0.1190  0.000198    3.310000e-07    0.001140    0.001510    0.000616    0.038600    0.000116    3.120000e-06    0.000512    0.000175    0.000174    9.920000e-08    0.000135    0.01110
24  0.474185    0.016275    0.000000    0.039373    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 1.000000    0.636497    0.074296    0.0923  0.0523  0.000044    0.0205  0.1180  0.000198    3.310000e-07    0.001130    0.001510    0.000616    0.038600    0.000115    3.120000e-06    0.000510    0.000175    0.000174    9.920000e-08    0.000135    0.01110
25  0.474185    0.121760    0.088021    0.039373    1.0 0.0 1.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.636497    0.074296    0.1390  0.0782  0.000067    0.0313  0.1750  0.000304    5.060000e-07    0.001670    0.002290    0.000941    0.059100    0.000177    4.780000e-06    0.000760    0.000266    0.000265    1.520000e-07    0.000207    0.01670
26  0.615385    0.150090    0.111661    0.239088    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.563468    0.084768    0.1350  0.0664  0.000073    0.0343  0.1300  0.000340    5.620000e-07    0.001240    0.002340    0.001040    0.065800    0.000196    5.320000e-06    0.000626    0.000290    0.000289    1.690000e-07    0.000224    0.01520
27  0.615385    0.150090    0.111661    0.239088    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.563468    0.084768    0.1400  0.0714  0.000073    0.0345  0.1450  0.000340    5.630000e-07    0.001390    0.002390    0.001040    0.066000    0.000196    5.330000e-06    0.000679    0.000292    0.000291    1.690000e-07    0.000226    0.01600
28  0.615385    0.263412    0.206221    0.239088    1.0 0.0 0.25    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.563468    0.084768    0.1770  0.0860  0.000096    0.0455  0.1630  0.000453    7.480000e-07    0.001580    0.003090    0.001380    0.087600    0.000260    7.080000e-06    0.000807    0.000385    0.000383    2.240000e-07    0.000297    0.01980
29  0.615385    0.376733    0.300782    0.239088    1.0 0.0 0.50    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.563468    0.084768    0.2180  0.1030  0.000120    0.0567  0.1940  0.000566    9.330000e-07    0.001850    0.003820    0.001730    0.109000    0.000325    8.830000e-06    0.000966    0.000480    0.000477    2.800000e-07    0.000370    0.02410
30  0.615385    0.489451    0.394839    0.239088    1.0 0.0 0.75    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.563468    0.084768    0.2580  0.1210  0.000143    0.0679  0.2240  0.000678    1.120000e-06    0.002140    0.004550    0.002070    0.131000    0.000389    1.060000e-05    0.001130    0.000574    0.000570    3.350000e-07    0.000442    0.02840
31  0.615385    0.601567    0.488393    0.239088    1.0 0.0 1.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.563468    0.084768    0.3320  0.1730  0.000171    0.0803  0.3590  0.000790    1.310000e-06    0.003430    0.005630    0.002430    0.153000    0.000456    1.240000e-05    0.001650    0.000681    0.000677    3.930000e-07    0.000527    0.03830
32  0.000000    0.156118    0.116691    0.239088    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.000000    0.000993    0.1090  0.0537  0.000059    0.0276  0.1050  0.000274    4.530000e-07    0.001000    0.001890    0.000839    0.053100    0.000158    4.290000e-06    0.000506    0.000234    0.000233    1.360000e-07    0.000181    0.01230
33  0.000000    0.156118    0.116691    0.239088    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000993    0.1140  0.0591  0.000059    0.0278  0.1220  0.000274    4.550000e-07    0.001170    0.001950    0.000843    0.053200    0.000158    4.300000e-06    0.000564    0.000236    0.000235    1.360000e-07    0.000183    0.01310
34  0.000000    0.267631    0.209742    0.239088    1.0 0.0 0.25    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.000000    0.000993    0.1490  0.0713  0.000082    0.0387  0.1350  0.000385    6.350000e-07    0.001290    0.002610    0.001180    0.074500    0.000221    6.020000e-06    0.000667    0.000327    0.000325    1.900000e-07    0.000252    0.01650
35  0.000000    0.379144    0.302793    0.239088    1.0 0.0 0.50    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.000000    0.000993    0.1900  0.0900  0.000105    0.0497  0.1680  0.000496    8.180000e-07    0.001600    0.003340    0.001510    0.095900    0.000285    7.750000e-06    0.000840    0.000420    0.000418    2.450000e-07    0.000324    0.02100
36  0.000000    0.491260    0.396348    0.239088    1.0 0.0 0.75    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.000000    0.000993    0.2310  0.1080  0.000128    0.0608  0.1990  0.000608    1.000000e-06    0.001900    0.004070    0.001850    0.117000    0.000349    9.480000e-06    0.001010    0.000514    0.000511    3.000000e-07    0.000396    0.02540
37  0.000000    0.601567    0.488393    0.239088    1.0 0.0 1.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.000000    0.000993    0.3020  0.1570  0.000156    0.0729  0.3260  0.000718    1.190000e-06    0.003120    0.005120    0.002210    0.139000    0.000415    1.130000e-05    0.001500    0.000619    0.000616    3.570000e-07    0.000479    0.03480
38  0.500000    0.435202    0.349571    1.000000    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.025434    0.000993    0.2220  0.1110  0.000118    0.0557  0.2200  0.000552    9.130000e-07    0.002100    0.003830    0.001690    0.107000    0.000318    8.640000e-06    0.001050    0.000472    0.000469    2.740000e-07    0.000365    0.02510
39  0.500000    0.435202    0.349571    1.000000    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.025434    0.000993    0.2330  0.1220  0.000120    0.0561  0.2540  0.000552    9.160000e-07    0.002430    0.003950    0.001700    0.107000    0.000319    8.660000e-06    0.001160    0.000477    0.000474    2.750000e-07    0.000369    0.02690
40  0.500000    0.630500    0.512536    1.000000    1.0 0.0 0.25    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.025434    0.000993    0.2960  0.1460  0.000159    0.0752  0.2850  0.000747    1.230000e-06    0.002720    0.005140    0.002280    0.144000    0.000430    1.170000e-05    0.001370    0.000637    0.000633    3.700000e-07    0.000491    0.03330
41  0.500410    0.423749    0.340014    1.000000    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.809761    1.000000    0.5250  0.2420  0.000294    0.1400  0.4370  0.001400    2.300000e-06    0.004170    0.009300    0.004260    0.270000    0.000802    2.180000e-05    0.002250    0.001180    0.001170    6.910000e-07    0.000910    0.05730
42  0.500410    0.423749    0.340014    1.000000    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.809761    1.000000    0.5360  0.2530  0.000296    0.1400  0.4710  0.001400    2.310000e-06    0.004510    0.009420    0.004270    0.270000    0.000803    2.180000e-05    0.002360    0.001190    0.001180    6.920000e-07    0.000914    0.05920
43  0.500410    0.622061    0.505494    1.000000    1.0 0.0 0.25    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.809761    1.000000    0.6000  0.2780  0.000336    0.1600  0.5020  0.001600    2.630000e-06    0.004790    0.010600    0.004860    0.308000    0.000915    2.490000e-05    0.002570    0.001350    0.001340    7.880000e-07    0.001040    0.06560
44  0.425661    0.066305    0.041747    0.113434    1.0 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.423123    0.076390    0.1060  0.0557  0.000054    0.0254  0.1170  0.000250    4.140000e-07    0.001120    0.001790    0.000769    0.048500    0.000144    3.920000e-06    0.000533    0.000216    0.000215    1.240000e-07    0.000167    0.01230
45  0.425661    0.066305    0.041747    0.113434    1.0 0.2 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.423123    0.076390    0.0877  0.0373  0.000052    0.0247  0.0593  0.000249    4.090000e-07    0.000567    0.001600    0.000755    0.048000    0.000142    3.880000e-06    0.000338    0.000208    0.000207    1.230000e-07    0.000160    0.00925
46  0.425661    0.074744    0.048789    0.113434    1.0 0.4 0.00    0.0 0.0 0.666667    0.423123    0.075692    0.0841  0.0322  0.000052    0.0252  0.0416  0.000257    4.200000e-07    0.000398    0.001580    0.000774    0.049400    0.000146    3.990000e-06    0.000282    0.000212    0.000211    1.260000e-07    0.000163    0.00851
47  1.000000    0.111513    0.079471    0.113434    1.0 0.0 0.25    0.0 0.0 0.666667    1.000000    0.024729    0.1060  0.0557  0.000054    0.0255  0.1170  0.000250    4.150000e-07    0.001120    0.001800    0.000771    0.048600    0.000145    3.930000e-06    0.000534    0.000216    0.000215    1.240000e-07    0.000167    0.01230
48  1.000000    0.165763    0.124739    0.113434    1.0 0.0 0.50    0.0 0.0 0.666667    1.000000    0.024729    0.1270  0.0659  0.000066    0.0309  0.1360  0.000304    5.040000e-07    0.001300    0.002160    0.000936    0.059000    0.000176    4.770000e-06    0.000629    0.000262    0.000261    1.510000e-07    0.000203    0.01460
49  1.000000    0.219409    0.169504    0.113434    1.0 0.0 0.75    0.0 0.0 0.666667    1.000000    0.024729    0.1480  0.0760  0.000077    0.0363  0.1560  0.000358    5.930000e-07    0.001490    0.002530    0.001100    0.069400    0.000206    5.600000e-06    0.000723    0.000308    0.000306    1.780000e-07    0.000238    0.01700
50  0.258287    0.001206    0.006287    0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.329916    0.040786    0.0588  0.0588  0.000015    0.0189  0.0969  0.000009    8.040000e-08    0.000951    0.002830    0.000129    0.001070    0.000024    7.110000e-07    0.000342    0.000060    0.000059    3.110000e-08    0.000044    0.01240
51  0.258287    0.001206    0.006287    0.000000    0.0 0.2 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.308259    0.036624    0.0423  0.0422  0.000012    0.0179  0.0467  0.000009    7.420000e-08    0.000470    0.002610    0.000115    0.000694    0.000021    6.660000e-07    0.000171    0.000053    0.000051    2.930000e-08    0.000038    0.00957
52  0.258287    0.001206    0.006287    0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.000000    0.329916    0.040786    0.0613  0.0612  0.000015    0.0190  0.1050  0.000009    8.110000e-08    0.001030    0.002860    0.000131    0.001130    0.000024    7.160000e-07    0.000368    0.000061    0.000060    3.130000e-08    0.000045    0.01280
53  0.258287    0.001206    0.006287    0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.333333    0.329916    0.040786    0.0599  0.0598  0.000015    0.0190  0.1000  0.000009    8.070000e-08    0.000982    0.002840    0.000130    0.001100    0.000024    7.130000e-07    0.000353    0.000061    0.000059    3.120000e-08    0.000045    0.01250
54  0.137212    0.000000    0.005088    0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.109655    0.029965    0.0519  0.0519  0.000013    0.0176  0.0806  0.000009    7.450000e-08    0.000793    0.002620    0.000119    0.000929    0.000022    6.610000e-07    0.000286    0.000055    0.000054    2.900000e-08    0.000040    0.01110
55  0.137212    0.000000    0.005088    0.000000    0.0 0.2 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.109655    0.027468    0.0386  0.0385  0.000012    0.0169  0.0398  0.000008    6.980000e-08    0.000403    0.002450    0.000108    0.000625    0.000020    6.280000e-07    0.000147    0.000049    0.000048    2.760000e-08    0.000035    0.00882
56  0.137212    0.000000    0.005088    0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.000000    0.109655    0.029965    0.0545  0.0545  0.000014    0.0177  0.0887  0.000009    7.530000e-08    0.000871    0.002650    0.000121    0.000989    0.000022    6.660000e-07    0.000314    0.000056    0.000055    2.920000e-08    0.000041    0.01150
57  0.137212    0.000000    0.005088    0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.333333    0.109655    0.029965    0.0530  0.0530  0.000014    0.0177  0.0840  0.000009    7.480000e-08    0.000826    0.002640    0.000120    0.000955    0.000022    6.630000e-07    0.000298    0.000056    0.000055    2.910000e-08    0.000041    0.01120
58  0.077118    0.001808    0.006887    0.039373    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.040474    0.052439    0.0617  0.0616  0.000016    0.0200  0.1010  0.000010    8.510000e-08    0.000987    0.003000    0.000137    0.001120    0.000025    7.530000e-07    0.000355    0.000064    0.000062    3.300000e-08    0.000047    0.01300
59  0.077118    0.001808    0.006887    0.039373    0.0 0.2 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.040474    0.051607    0.0456  0.0455  0.000013    0.0194  0.0503  0.000009    8.000000e-08    0.000507    0.002810    0.000124    0.000749    0.000023    7.180000e-07    0.000185    0.000057    0.000055    3.160000e-08    0.000041    0.01030
60  0.077118    0.001808    0.006887    0.039373    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.000000    0.040474    0.052439    0.0645  0.0644  0.000016    0.0201  0.1090  0.000010    8.590000e-08    0.001070    0.003030    0.000139    0.001180    0.000025    7.580000e-07    0.000385    0.000065    0.000063    3.320000e-08    0.000048    0.01340
61  0.077118    0.001808    0.006887    0.039373    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.333333    0.040474    0.052439    0.0629  0.0628  0.000016    0.0201  0.1040  0.000010    8.540000e-08    0.001020    0.003010    0.000138    0.001150    0.000025    7.550000e-07    0.000368    0.000064    0.000063    3.310000e-08    0.000047    0.01320
62  0.474185    0.000000    0.005088    0.039373    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.636497    0.075746    0.0717  0.0717  0.000018    0.0221  0.1230  0.000011    9.440000e-08    0.001210    0.003330    0.000153    0.001320    0.000028    8.330000e-07    0.000433    0.000072    0.000070    3.640000e-08    0.000053    0.01490
63  0.474185    0.000000    0.005088    0.039373    0.0 0.2 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.636497    0.061595    0.0487  0.0486  0.000014    0.0201  0.0568  0.000010    8.320000e-08    0.000570    0.002930    0.000130    0.000810    0.000024    7.460000e-07    0.000207    0.000059    0.000058    3.280000e-08    0.000043    0.01090
64  0.474185    0.000000    0.005088    0.039373    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.000000    0.636497    0.075746    0.0741  0.0740  0.000018    0.0222  0.1310  0.000011    9.510000e-08    0.001280    0.003350    0.000155    0.001380    0.000028    8.370000e-07    0.000459    0.000073    0.000071    3.660000e-08    0.000054    0.01530
65  0.474185    0.000000    0.005088    0.039373    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.333333    0.636497    0.075746    0.0727  0.0726  0.000018    0.0221  0.1260  0.000011    9.470000e-08    0.001240    0.003340    0.000154    0.001350    0.000028    8.340000e-07    0.000444    0.000072    0.000070    3.650000e-08    0.000053    0.01510
66  0.615385    0.107294    0.111835    0.239088    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.000000    0.563468    0.086567    0.0987  0.0986  0.000027    0.0360  0.1400  0.000017    1.510000e-07    0.001390    0.005320    0.000239    0.001720    0.000044    1.350000e-06    0.000501    0.000110    0.000108    5.910000e-08    0.000080    0.02140
67  0.615385    0.107294    0.111835    0.239088    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.333333    0.563468    0.086567    0.0959  0.0958  0.000026    0.0359  0.1310  0.000017    1.500000e-07    0.001300    0.005290    0.000237    0.001660    0.000044    1.340000e-06    0.000471    0.000109    0.000107    5.880000e-08    0.000079    0.02100
68  0.615385    0.201929    0.205989    0.239088    0.0 0.0 0.25    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.563468    0.086567    0.1240  0.1230  0.000034    0.0476  0.1620  0.000023    1.980000e-07    0.001610    0.006980    0.000312    0.002120    0.000058    1.770000e-06    0.000585    0.000143    0.000140    7.790000e-08    0.000104    0.02720
69  0.615385    0.297167    0.300743    0.239088    0.0 0.0 0.50    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.563468    0.086567    0.1490  0.1490  0.000042    0.0592  0.1860  0.000029    2.460000e-07    0.001860    0.008660    0.000385    0.002520    0.000071    2.200000e-06    0.000673    0.000177    0.000173    9.680000e-08    0.000127    0.03310
70  0.615385    0.391802    0.394897    0.239088    0.0 0.0 0.75    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.563468    0.086567    0.1760  0.1760  0.000050    0.0708  0.2150  0.000034    2.940000e-07    0.002150    0.010400    0.000459    0.002960    0.000085    2.630000e-06    0.000781    0.000211    0.000206    1.160000e-07    0.000152    0.03920
71  0.615385    0.485232    0.487851    0.239088    0.0 0.0 1.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.563468    0.086567    0.2370  0.2360  0.000063    0.0836  0.3500  0.000041    3.520000e-07    0.003460    0.012400    0.000559    0.004180    0.000103    3.130000e-06    0.001250    0.000259    0.000253    1.370000e-07    0.000188    0.05090
72  0.000000    0.112116    0.116633    0.239088    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.001665    0.0828  0.0827  0.000022    0.0291  0.1230  0.000014    1.220000e-07    0.001220    0.004310    0.000194    0.001460    0.000036    1.090000e-06    0.000439    0.000090    0.000088    4.770000e-08    0.000066    0.01780
73  0.000000    0.112116    0.116633    0.239088    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.333333    0.000000    0.001665    0.0797  0.0796  0.000021    0.0290  0.1140  0.000014    1.210000e-07    0.001130    0.004280    0.000192    0.001390    0.000035    1.080000e-06    0.000407    0.000089    0.000087    4.750000e-08    0.000064    0.01730
74  0.000000    0.205546    0.209588    0.239088    0.0 0.0 0.25    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.000000    0.001665    0.1040  0.1040  0.000029    0.0404  0.1360  0.000020    1.680000e-07    0.001350    0.005920    0.000264    0.001780    0.000049    1.500000e-06    0.000489    0.000122    0.000119    6.600000e-08    0.000088    0.02300
75  0.000000    0.298975    0.302542    0.239088    0.0 0.0 0.50    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.000000    0.001665    0.1320  0.1320  0.000037    0.0519  0.1670  0.000025    2.160000e-07    0.001670    0.007600    0.000338    0.002240    0.000063    1.930000e-06    0.000605    0.000155    0.000152    8.480000e-08    0.000112    0.02920
76  0.000000    0.393008    0.396096    0.239088    0.0 0.0 0.75    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.000000    0.001665    0.1590  0.1590  0.000045    0.0635  0.1990  0.000031    2.640000e-07    0.001980    0.009280    0.000413    0.002690    0.000077    2.360000e-06    0.000720    0.000190    0.000185    1.040000e-07    0.000137    0.03540
77  0.000000    0.484629    0.487251    0.239088    0.0 0.0 1.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.000000    0.001665    0.2160  0.2160  0.000057    0.0759  0.3230  0.000037    3.190000e-07    0.003190    0.011200    0.000508    0.003830    0.000093    2.840000e-06    0.001150    0.000235    0.000230    1.250000e-07    0.000171    0.04640
78  0.500000    0.347800    0.351118    1.000000    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.025434    0.000832    0.1590  0.1580  0.000043    0.0583  0.2230  0.000028    2.440000e-07    0.002210    0.008600    0.000386    0.002770    0.000071    2.180000e-06    0.000799    0.000178    0.000174    9.550000e-08    0.000129    0.03450
79  0.500000    0.343580    0.346920    1.000000    0.0 0.2 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.025434    0.000832    0.1230  0.1220  0.000037    0.0565  0.1130  0.000027    2.320000e-07    0.001150    0.008150    0.000356    0.001940    0.000067    2.090000e-06    0.000424    0.000162    0.000158    9.200000e-08    0.000115    0.02850
80  0.500000    0.357444    0.360713    1.000000    0.0 0.4 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.025434    0.000832    0.1150  0.1140  0.000037    0.0577  0.0793  0.000028    2.350000e-07    0.000837    0.008270    0.000358    0.001730    0.000067    2.130000e-06    0.000312    0.000162    0.000158    9.380000e-08    0.000115    0.02740
81  0.500000    0.354430    0.357715    1.000000    0.0 0.6 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.025434    0.000000    0.1080  0.1070  0.000036    0.0570  0.0598  0.000027    2.320000e-07    0.000649    0.008140    0.000351    0.001580    0.000066    2.100000e-06    0.000245    0.000158    0.000154    9.260000e-08    0.000111    0.02620
82  0.500000    0.342978    0.346321    1.000000    0.0 1.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.025434    0.000832    0.0994  0.0992  0.000034    0.0555  0.0402  0.000027    2.250000e-07    0.000460    0.007890    0.000338    0.001410    0.000064    2.040000e-06    0.000178    0.000152    0.000148    9.000000e-08    0.000107    0.02460
83  0.500000    0.839060    0.839879    1.000000    0.0 0.0 0.75    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.025434    0.000832    0.3090  0.3090  0.000085    0.1190  0.4070  0.000058    4.970000e-07    0.004050    0.017500    0.000780    0.005300    0.000144    4.440000e-06    0.001470    0.000359    0.000351    1.950000e-07    0.000259    0.06810
84  0.500000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.0 0.0 1.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.025434    0.000832    0.4070  0.4060  0.000106    0.1410  0.6170  0.000069    5.940000e-07    0.006090    0.020900    0.000945    0.007230    0.000174    5.270000e-06    0.002190    0.000439    0.000429    2.310000e-07    0.000320    0.08700
85  1.000000    0.344183    0.347520    1.000000    0.0 0.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.790521    0.220578    0.2170  0.2160  0.000058    0.0779  0.3140  0.000038    3.270000e-07    0.003100    0.011500    0.000518    0.003800    0.000096    2.910000e-06    0.001120    0.000240    0.000234    1.280000e-07    0.000174    0.04680
86  1.000000    0.362869    0.366111    1.000000    0.0 1.0 0.00    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.790521    0.192278    0.1340  0.1330  0.000046    0.0746  0.0542  0.000036    3.020000e-07    0.000621    0.010600    0.000455    0.001890    0.000086    2.740000e-06    0.000239    0.000205    0.000199    1.210000e-07    0.000143    0.03310
87  1.000000    0.509946    0.512439    1.000000    0.0 0.0 0.25    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.790521    0.220578    0.2720  0.2720  0.000073    0.0986  0.3900  0.000048    4.140000e-07    0.003860    0.014600    0.000655    0.004760    0.000121    3.680000e-06    0.001390    0.000303    0.000296    1.620000e-07    0.000220    0.05890
88  1.000000    0.675708    0.677358    1.000000    0.0 0.0 0.50    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.790521    0.220578    0.3200  0.3190  0.000087    0.1190  0.4420  0.000058    4.980000e-07    0.004380    0.017500    0.000785    0.005540    0.000145    4.440000e-06    0.001580    0.000362    0.000354    1.950000e-07    0.000263    0.06970
89  1.000000    0.840868    0.841678    1.000000    0.0 0.0 0.75    1.0 1.0 0.666667    0.790521    0.220578    0.3660  0.3650  0.000100    0.1390  0.4890  0.000068    5.810000e-07    0.004860    0.020500    0.000914    0.006290    0.000169    5.190000e-06    0.001760    0.000421    0.000412    2.280000e-07    0.000305    0.08030



lin_regressor = LinearRegression()

# pass the order of your polynomial here  
poly = PolynomialFeatures(1)

# convert to be used further to linear regression
X_transform = poly.fit_transform(x_train)

# fit this to Linear Regressor
linear_regg=lin_regressor.fit(X_transform,y_train) 



linear_regg.coef_


# get the predictions
X_test_transform = poly.fit_transform(x_test)
y_preds_polynomial_regressor = lin_regressor.predict(X_test_transform)


from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

crossvalidation_poly = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)

for i in range(1,11):
    poly_cross_validation = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
    X_current = poly.fit_transform(X_normalized)
    model = lin_regressor.fit(X_current, y_for_normalized)
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X_current,y_for_normalized, scoring='r2', cv=crossvalidation_poly,
 n_jobs=1)
    
    print("\n\nDegree-"+str(i)+" polynomial: R^2 for every fold: " + str(np.abs(scores)))

    print('\033[1m'+"Degree-"+str(i)+'\033[1m'+"polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: " + str(np.mean(np.abs(scores))) + '\033[0m'+ ", STD: " + str(np.std(scores)))


Degree-1 polynomial: R^2 for every fold: [0.76295904 0.96271418 0.94310536 0.91732566 0.96612939 0.97031929
 0.9913522  0.99347979 0.87728285 0.96961128]
Degree-1polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: 0.9354279053365726, STD: 0.06639546264706242
Degree-2 polynomial: R^2 for every fold: [0.91315584 0.98834316 0.95305722 0.96135075 0.95088178 0.98469973
 0.85601024 0.93466868 0.90153858 0.98206352]
Degree-2polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: 0.9425769506851147, STD: 0.04008167950913074


Degree-3 polynomial: R^2 for every fold: [0.99193642 0.94930724 0.97407922 0.98482365 0.95087103 0.96237042
 0.8981392  0.97702263 0.98042845 0.9590484 ]
Degree-3polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: 0.9628026644379586, STD: 0.0254830753054201


Degree-4 polynomial: R^2 for every fold: [0.98440571 0.97680078 0.95419355 0.98656256 0.9258109  0.93366813
 0.96516026 0.961787   0.98939286 0.93072549]
Degree-4polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: 0.9608507236588766, STD: 0.022853823542880715
```

Answer (score 0):

On Increasing the polynomial degree, it isn't necessary that R2 will increase because R2 basically means the accuracy. When you increase the polynomial degree the line shape changes a bit, that's why on increasing it is not necessary that it'll fit the relation perfectly.

Comment: Also, How you have made sure that the input and output are not linear? According to me with 0.95 R2 most of them should have linearity relation except some.

Comment: Thank you for passing by. I know that based on the theory behind the problem. But is there anyway I can be very confident that my model is really linear?